# PHP How to compare each array value with my specified value?

Tags: php, mysql

Say for example this is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ...";
$exec_query = mysql_query($query, $db_connect);
$fetchdetails = mysql_fetch_array($exec_query);
```

I am using an `if` condition like this:

```
if ($fetchdetails['field_name'] == 3) {
 do something;
}

else {
}
```

But in this, only 1 row is compared from the `fetchdetails` array. What can I do to compare each row in that array with 3? I don't want any OOP's solutions, please, I want to stick with traditional coding. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this:

```
while($fetchdetails = mysql_fetch_array($exec_query)) {
 if ($fetchdetails['field_name'] == 3) {
  do something;
 }

 else {
 }

}
```

That's because, with the `while(...)` condition, you'll iterate over all db (selected) records.
The loop will stop in an automatic way as soon as `mysql_fetch_array` finish record.

I'll remember you that `mysql_fetch_array`

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. (from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php))

and that will allow "you" to stop iteration process.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to compare every row of the $fetchdetails array, then

```
foreach($fetchdetails as $index => $value) {
    if($value == 3) { 
        // do something
    }
}
```

Should do it! If you want to iterate over every SQL value, see the other answer.